# Modificar archivo JSON o convertirlo a JS. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo un archivo JSON el cual hace de "base de datos", puesto que aún no tengo conocimientos de ese tipo.

```
{
  "words": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "word": "Silla",
      "principal": "http://pngimg.com/uploads/chair/chair_PNG6860.png",
      "engword": "Chair",
      "engimg": "Imagen de ingles",
      "deuword": "Stuhl",
      "deuimg": "Imagen de aleman"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "word": "Gilbert",
      "principal": "http://pngimg.com/uploads/chair/chair_PNG6860.png",
      "engword": "Chair",
      "engimg": "Imagen de ingles",
      "deuword": "Stuhl",
      "deuimg": "Imagen de aleman"
    }
  ]
}
```

Ese es mi archivo JSON y me gustaría convertirlo a JS o algo parecido para poder editarlo mediante mis componentes de React.

Comment: Si, bueno. La cosa es que pueda tener una key "learned": false y simplemente presionando un botón pueda pasarlo a true. Osea, que tambien se "guarde"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSON** es una especie de acrónimo formado de la palabra **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation, y es una forma de guardar objetos de Js en texto, por esa razón es posible leer el json de una forma tan natural como hacer lo siguiente en tu archivo.

```
import React from 'react'
import { words } from './miswords.json' // O el nombre de tu archivo

export default () => (
  <ul>
    {words.map(({ word, id }) => (
      <li key={id}>{word}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
)
```

Y de esa forma puedes **consumir** esos datos.
Sin embargo si quieres manipular la opción de `"learned": "true"`, desde un navegador eso ya es otra cosa. Pues debería de considerar que cada persona que entre desde su navegador  debe de tener su propio archivo (para que el enfoque que propones funcione) o conectarlo a una base de datos (que eso es lo más obvio). Una forma sencilla que podrías hacer es **persitir** tu estado con alguna herramienta que tenga acceso a [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) y puedas guardar en cada cliente su estado.

Comment: Ah perfecto, muchas gracias. Supongo que lo mejor será aprender un poco de bases de datos para hacer de la mejor manera lo que quiero.

Answer (score 0):

Quisiera saber como con este mismo ejemplo puedo consultar un solo campos del JSON, sin tener que llamarlos a todos.

Ejemplo: quiero consultar solo

"engword": "Chair"

¿Cómo lo hago? Agradezco mucho la ayuda.